# linear equation equality constraint - which row to remove?

Tags: linear-algebra

In this question, there is a linear equation $Ax=b$, and
a particular element of $x$ is constrained to a known value.

The "move to the right hand side" approach (see below) results
in an overdetermined system.  Because it is overdetermined, one row can be removed.

Which row should be removed? I would think that, if the original system is full rank, **any** row can be removed.  However, I've seen several papers say that if $x_2$ is constrained, row 2 should be the one removed.  Why?  (Further, I don't see this topic treated an any of the linear algebra books - Strang, etc.)

Further explanation, what I mean by the "move to the right hand side" approach:
Let's say the second element $x_2$ is the one constrained.

Expand $Ax=b$ as

> $a1 \cdot x_1 + a2 \cdot x_2 + ... = b$

for columns a1, a2, ....
Subtract $a2 \cdot x_2$ from both sides of the equation, giving

$a1 \cdot x_1 + \quad a3 \cdot x_3 ... = b - a2 \cdot x_2$.
Now the system is has one more row than column, so we should be able to drop one row.
Can any row be dropped, or should it be row 2 ?

Comment: If the system has a solution, I would say any row could be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Since the system is overdetermined, it's not guaranteed that the system has solutions at all. The trivial example is the system
$$\begin{cases}x_1=1,\\x_2=1\end{cases}$$
with a constraint $x_1=0$.

If we suppose that the constraint is compatible with the solution of the initial system, and that system was of full rank, then you can remove any row - you can change their order without losing solutions, after all. If the said system was not of full rank, then you need to invent something else, depending on the exact structure of the system.